# configuring flask-socketio with nginx,gunicorn and supervisor

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord, flask-socketio

I am having hard time configuring flask-socketio to work with nginx,gunicorn and supervisor. Every thing works fine on local mechine i have tested all events and functions and they are working well. But I am unable to make it work on production server.
The only thin i get in **frontend.log** is
**INFO|engineio.server               |server.py:150 **init**             ]: Server initialized for eventlet.**

Here are my configuration.

this is my **`__init__.py`**

```
import os
import logging
import gevent
import datetime
import rollbar
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from gevent.queue import Queue
from gevent.event import AsyncResult
import zmq.green as zmq

from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

# Greens the postgress connector

try:
    import psycogreen.gevent

    psycogreen.gevent.patch_psycopg()
except ImportError:
    pass

from rauth.service import OAuth2Service

from flask import Flask, Request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager, current_user
from flask_assets import Environment
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES

from app.util import setup_logging
from app.exceptions import TimeoutError, BackendError
import app.exceptions

socketio = SocketIO()

flask_app = None


# Have to use an actor pattern because we cannot allow more than one request to
# be pending at a time.
class Backend(gevent.Greenlet):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Backend, self).__init__()

        self.inbox = Queue()
        self.zmq_context = zmq.Context()
        self.zmq_socket = None
        self.init_socket()

    def init_socket(self):
        zmq_socket = self.zmq_socket
        if zmq_socket is not None:
            zmq_socket.close(0)

        zmq_socket = self.zmq_context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        zmq_socket.connect(flask_app.config["SERVER_ZMQ_URI"])
        self.zmq_socket = zmq_socket

    def process(self, request):
        zmq_socket = self.zmq_socket

        poller = zmq.Poller()
        poller.register(zmq_socket, zmq.POLLIN)

        zmq_socket.send_json({
            "command": request["command"],
            "arguments": request["arguments"]
        })
        sockets = dict(poller.poll(10 * 1000))

        if zmq_socket not in sockets:
            self.init_socket()
            result = request["result"]
            result.set_exception(TimeoutError("The request to the backend timed out."))
            return

        received = zmq_socket.recv_json()

        result = request["result"]
        if received["success"]:
            result.set(received["result"])
        else:
            result.set_exception(BackendError(received["result"]))

    def _run(self):
        while True:
            self.process(self.inbox.get())

    def send(self, command, **kwargs):
        result = AsyncResult()
        self.inbox.put({
            "command": command,
            "arguments": kwargs,
            "result": result
        })
        return result.get()


class RollbarRequest(Request):
    @property
    def rollbar_person(self):
        if current_user.is_anonymous:
            return {
                "id": 0,
                "username": "anonymous"
            }
        return {
            "id": current_user.id,
            "username": current_user.name,
            "email": current_user.email_address
        }


def create_app(*args, **kwargs):
    global flask_app
    global l

    app_mode = os.environ.get("APP_MODE")

    assert app_mode is not None, "APP_MODE environment variable must be set"

    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    flask_app.request_class = RollbarRequest
    flask_app.config.from_object("config.mode_{}".format(app_mode))
    flask_app.config["APP_MODE"] = app_mode
    setup_logging(flask_app.config["LOGGING_LEVEL"])
    l = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    l.info("starting in mode {}".format(app_mode))

    if not flask_app.config["DEBUG"]:
        rollbar.init(
            flask_app.config["ROLLBAR_API_KEY"],
            app_mode,
            allow_logging_basic_config=False
        )

    flask_app.jinja_env.globals.update(
        current_year=lambda: datetime.datetime.now().year
    )

    if not flask_app.debug:
        flask_app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(flask_app.wsgi_app)

    flask_app.db = SQLAlchemy(flask_app)
    flask_app.bcrypt = Bcrypt(flask_app)
    flask_app.assets = Environment(flask_app)
    Bootstrap(flask_app)
    flask_app.images = UploadSet("images", IMAGES)
    configure_uploads(flask_app, flask_app.images)

       
    from app import views
    from app import models
    from app import commands

    flask_app.backend = Backend()
    flask_app.backend.start()

    app.exceptions.register(flask_app)
    socketio.init_app(flask_app)
    return flask_app
```

This is my **manage.py**

```
import gevent.monkey

gevent.monkey.patch_all()

import click
from app import create_app, socketio
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup


@click.group(cls=FlaskGroup, create_app=create_app, add_default_commands=False)
def cli():
    """App management script."""
    socketio.run(create_app, debug=False, log_output=True, async_mode='eventlet')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

**nginx configuration** file inside /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
#pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}
# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application my_app_name {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls off;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            #deny play all;
            record off;
            on_publish http://127.0.0.1:5000/authenticate_user;
            on_publish_done  http://127.0.0.1:5000/end_live;
        }
    }
}

http {
                directio 512;
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        server {
                listen 8080;

                location / {
                        # Disable cache
                        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

                        # CORS setup
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

                        # allow CORS preflight requests
                        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                                return 204;
                        }
                        types {
                                application/dash+xml mpd;
                                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                                video/mp2t ts;
                        }
                          root /mnt/;
                }
    }
}
```

this is my **app configuration** file inside /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name dev.my_app_name.com
    client_max_body_size 32M;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
    ssl_certificate keys/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key keys/key.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_password_file keys/key_phrase;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

    }
    location /var/ {
        internal;
        alias /home/%(username)s/var/;
    }
    location /static/ {
        location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
            expires 30d;
        }
        expires 1h;
        alias /home/%(username)s/my_app_name/app/static/;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location /robots.txt {
        expires 1h;
        root /home/%(username)s/my_app_name/app/static/html;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

and this is my **supervisor configuration** for app

```
[group:app]
programs=gunicorn, backend
[program:gunicorn]
command= /home/ubuntu/app-pyvenv/bin/gunicorn 'app:create_app()' -c config/gunicorn.py -p ../var/run/gunicorn.pid
environment=APP_MODE="production"
directory=/home/ubuntu/my_app_name
user=ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/var/log/frontend.log

[program:backend]
command=/home/ubuntu/my_app_name/manage.py server execbackend -p ../var/run/backend.pid
environment=APP_MODE="production",LC_ALL="C.UTF-8",LANG="C.UTF-8"
directory=/home/ubuntu/my_app_name
user=ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/var/log/backend.log
```

Comment: How come you get "initialized for eventlet" when you are clearly using gevent? Have you installed eventlet as well? Try uninstalling it.

Comment: @Miguel I have installed both and tried using eventlet and gevent as well.

Comment: Either add an explicit selection in the `async_mode` argument to `SocketIO()`, or else leave installed only the one that you want to use.

Comment: @Miguel I have uninstalled eventlet and in manage.py     socketio.run(create_app, debug=False, log_output=True) changed to this. Now its says "initialized for gevent" and nothing else.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you are passing a function in the `app` argument, that's another problem. How do you start your app? Looking at your code, you created a `FlaskGroup`, but did not create a command.

Comment: @Miguel I am fairly new to python and flask, and don`t know much about creating command,I think the app is  run using supervisor with manage.py file. can you please point me to a direction about how can i make it work.

Comment: Why don't you use a normal start up script, without a Flask group? See the Flask-SocketIO documentation for the example here: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#initialization.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks, I made it work with flask group